# Run a application after saving mail attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

Need to run an application after saving attachment with below script.

how do i call it After end sub?

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = "C:\New folder\tmp\"
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
         objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
         Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You should give more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open Application in VBA

```
Sub OpenApp()
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim Path As String

    '// Application Path
    Path = "C:\Program Files\blabla.exe"

    x = Shell(Path, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks Omar. All i need now is to call this sub from my  previous sub. Works well. Thanks again